# laravel avoid multiple Select's Option in blade

Tags: php, laravel

simply in my controller i have this collections:

```php
$category = Category::with('users')->find($id);
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
```

and in front end i try to check which users in `$users` is into `$category->users`, like with:

in `Category` model which that belong to `User` i have one or multiple stored users and i would like checked html `option` if each `$category` has user which that is into `$user`

```
<select class="form-control multiselect-filtering" multiple="multiple" name="users[]">
    @foreach ($category->users as $guser)
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <option value="{{$guser->id}}"
                    @if ($guser->id == $user->id)
                       selected="selected"
                    @else
                       ''
                    @endif
                        >
            {{$user->username}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

this code and compare works, but i have multiple `<option>` which they are maybe `selected` or not. how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is it that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @StevenPss i updated post, please review again, thanks

Comment: So, you are trying to populate the select with all the users and mark as selected just the ones there are in the `$category->users` collection. Thts right?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ yes, thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the collection which is in the `$users` variable, and use the [contains](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains) method to check if the current user id in the loop is contained in the `$category->users` collection.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
     <option value="{{$user->id}}"
           @if ( $category->users ->contains('id', $user->id))
                   selected="selected"
           @endif
      >
            {{$user->username}}
        </option>
@endforeach
```